# Cannot fetch data with react localhost from deployed Strapi app on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, database, heroku, configuration, strapi

I have deployed my strapi app on Heroku now and have used the postgres addon.

I added all postgres info into the required files, but still cannot fetch data from strapi.
I am not sure to have localhost/1337 or my strapi app url and where to have it. I get an error when trying to fetch

```
--- frontend ---
// App.js
// apollo client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

--- backend ---
config => server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
});
```

config => database.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: 'sqlite',
    connection: {
      filename: path.join(__dirname, '..', env('DATABASE_FILENAME', '.tmp/data.db')),
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
  },
});
```

config => env => production -> server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  proxy: true,
  url: env('MY_HEROKU_URL'),
  app: { 
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS')
  },
})
```

config => env => production => database.js

```
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;
const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
console.log(config)

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
      host: config.host,
      port: config.port,
      database: config.database,
      user: config.user,
      password: config.password,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
    },
    debug: false,
  },
});
```